# Angular interval vs clearInterval

Tags: angularjs

I just fixed a defect in our code which was caused by `clearInterval` being used instead of `$interval.cancel`. As I know this code worked in the past (Angular 1.2 or something I think), I wonder if there have been any changes to the `$interval` implementation. This is esp. considering that the angular documentation [claims](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval):

> Angular's wrapper for `window.setInterval`

Comment: Whatever that change, the documented way of clearing an angular interval is not to use clearInterval, so you should not use that. How it wraps setInterval() is angular'sbusiness. You should only use the public, documented API.

Comment: angular wrapper for this function is needed to apply changes in callback function to controller scope. (the following is just guessing) looks like it should be related to $digest cycle changes or anything with that.

Comment: @JBNizet: thanks captain obvious, I'll tell the guy who broke it ;)